# How to calculate percentage

Tags: java, servlets, percentage

The code below gets the failed indexes from a text file and prints it to a webpage and the lower loop does same but for the passes. I want to calculate the percentages and I have tried the code below but it returns `0.0%`.

Please help as I am a novice programmer.

```
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = (secondLine.indexOf(failures, i) + 1)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
        feedbackString += "<strong style='color: red;'><li>Failed: </strong><strong>" + i + "</strong> - " + "out of " + resultString.length() + " tests.<br>";
    }

    int j = 0;
    while ((j = (secondLine.indexOf(passed, j) + 1)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(j);
        feedbackString += "<strong style='color: green;'><li>Passed: </strong><strong>" + j + "</strong> - Well done.</li>";  
    }

    totalScore = j * 100 / resultString.length();
    System.out.println(totalScore);
    feedbackString += "Your submission scored " + totalScore + "%.<br>";
```

Comment: What is resultString, and why do you use it's length to get the result ?

Comment: resultString is a variable that holds different length for different assesment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make your division a floating point division :

```
totalScore = (double)j * 100 / resultString.length();
```

That's assuming `totalScore` is a double.

Otherwise, `j * 100 / resultString.length()` would use `int` division, so if `resultString.length()` > 100, the result would be 0.

As Tom mentioned, the condition of the `while` loop :

```
while ((j = (secondLine.indexOf(passed, j) + 1)) > 0)
```

ensures the it will end only once j <= 0. Therefore, it's no wonder `(double)j * 100 / resultString.length()` is 0.

If you want to count the number of passes you need a second counter :

```
int j = 0;
int passes = 0;
while ((j = (secondLine.indexOf(passed, j) + 1)) > 0) {
    passes++;
    System.out.println(j);
    feedbackString += "<strong style='color: green;'><li>Passed: </strong><strong>" + j + "</strong> - Well done.</li>";  
}
```

Then

```
totalScore = (double)passes * 100 / resultString.length();
```

Comment: @Eran how about `totalScore = passes * 100.0 / resultString.length();`?

Comment: I have seen the edited post and its exactly same as my code above except for the passes++ which still does same as I can count the number of passes but can t calculate the percentage as j=0 outside of the loop which gives me 0.0% I am very confused :(. trying your code gives me 100% in all assesment

Comment: @buzz since j is 0 after the loop,  you need a separate counter to count the number of passes. If you get 100%, that means the number of passes is the same as resultString.length(). I'm not entirely sure what that means, since you only showed us a small part of your code.

Comment: when I created another while loop with my calculations inside of it. This is what the output looks like: counter1
Total Score:8.333333333333334
counter2
Total Score:16.666666666666668
counter3
Total Score:25.0
counter5
Total Score:41.666666666666664
counter6
Total Score:50.0
counter7
Total Score:58.333333333333336
counter8
Total Score:66.66666666666667
counter9
Total Score:75.0
counter10
Total Score:83.33333333333333
counter12
Total Score:100.0
counter13
Total Score:108.33333333333333
counter15
Total Score:125.0. And 0% when outside the loop. counter is exactly the same in your last edit. thxs

Comment: Hi all thanks for your help! I have final resolved this task with the help of the second counter @Eran suggested. I was suppose to divide by secondLine since it has the length of each assessment and not the resultString. sorry for been such a burden :D.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that j is not the count of failures, it's an index to the failure. Since you indexOf returns -1 in case it didn't find the element and you use it to mark the end of search, it will always be -1. Add 1 and you always get j == 0.

You can do it that way:

```
String secondLine = "pfpffpfffp";
char failures = 'f';
char passed = 'p';

ArrayList<Integer> failuresList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> passedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String feedbackString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < secondLine.length(); i++) {
  char o = secondLine.charAt(i);
  if (o == failures) {
    failuresList.add(i);
  } else {
    passedList.add(i);
  }
}

int countFailures = failuresList.size();
int countPassed = passedList.size();
int countTotal = countFailures + countPassed;

for (int i = 0; i < failuresList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(failuresList.get(i));
    feedbackString += "<strong style='color: red;'><li>Failed: </strong><strong>" + i + "</strong> - " + "out of " + countTotal + " tests.<br>";
}
for (int i = 0; i < passedList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(passedList.get(i));
    feedbackString += "<strong style='color: green;'><li>Passed: </strong><strong>" + i + "</strong> - Well done.</li>"; 
}

double totalScore = countPassed * 100.0 / countTotal;
System.out.println(totalScore);
feedbackString += "Your submission scored " + totalScore + "%.<br>";
System.out.println(feedbackString);
```